# Nginx + MP4 module: buffer limits are being ignored

Tags: nginx, streaming, buffer

I have an `nginx/1.2.3` server compiled with `--with-http_mp4_module` as a pseudostreaming server.

Streaming and seeking works fine except buffering. Tt seems like the buffer directives are being completely ignored.

Here are the `location` declaration for the streaming part;

```
location  /video_dump/ {
        alias /var/www/mp4/;
        mp4;
        mp4_buffer_size     512k;
        mp4_max_buffer_size 1m;
}
```

The above `location` is in the `server` block of an https server.

I know that the buffer directives are being ignored because as soon as the video starts streaming it starts getting downloaded without stopping at the declared limit.

Any takers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mp4_buffer_size` and `mp4_max_buffer_size` refer to the memory used by nginx to process the MP4 file (read MOOV atom etc) to be served and not to the client-side steam buffer.